# Fastest way to reach St-Jean-Pied-de-Port from Barcelona or other Spanish airports

Tags: spain, hiking, walking, summer, pilgrimages

This summer I would like to walk on the Camino de Santiago. I want to start from St-Jean-Pied-de-Port and walk for 300 km. My idea is to reach Barcelona by plane from Italy, and then go to the starting point by train or bus. My question is:

Does anyone, that has already made this trip, know some fast way to reach St-Jean-Pied-de-Port? I mean, how many trains or buses do I have to take? I've already done some research, but I'm very confused.

Furthermore, have you flown back to your country from the same airport you arrived at the beginning?

Comment: What exactly are you confused about ?

Comment: Also, I've edited out the parts in your question about "best" and "tips" as these are subjective and will likely get your question closed

Comment: [Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Barcelona/Saint-Jean-Pied-de-Port) is a good starting point but why have you settled on Barcelona? Saint-Jean-Pied-de-Port being in France, it seems it would make more sense to fly to France first but even in Spain, other cities/airports might have better connections.

Comment: in particular, between Barcelona and St-Jean-Pied-de-Port, there is a full range of mountains, i.e. you need to go all the way around. The fastest way between Barcelona and St-Jean-Pied-de-Port is likely flying to Bordeaux or Biarritz

Comment: @Vince For a few thousand years, mankind has been able to build roads and later even railways in mountainous areas. Taking the train from Barcelona to Pamplona (3:45h) and then the bus from there to Saint-Jean-Pied-de-Port (1:45h) seems like a very feasible option to me if DamianFox for some reason has to fly via Barcelona.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo oh yeah definitely, I'd be happy to hear such a requirement. But taking the train all the way from Italy is probably an even better journey.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo So almost 2 hours for 70 km (and a bus that only runs once daily) and a total time close to what it takes to go from Paris to Saint-Jean-Pied-de-Port (taking connections into account), I think you're just making Vince's case for him, no need to be sarcastic. And the question explicitly says "or other Spanish airports"...

Comment: @Relaxed The bus runs three times daily, not once. By car, it's about 500km from Barcelona to Saint-Jean-Pied-de-Port, while train and bus takes you 6:45h, including the waiting time in Pamplona. Short of 7 hours for overland public transport over a distance of 500km is not bad at all, compared to most other parts of Europe.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Barcelona-Pamplona is good, Pamplona-Saint-Jean-Pied-de-Port not so much, that's a simple fact confirmed by your own comments. 7 hours (ignoring transfer from the airport to the train station and the assumption that the plane is landing at a convenient time) is doable but like I already said, more or less the time it takes from the center of Paris. So Vince point stands and you still have absolutely no reason to be so sarcastic (politely mentioning this option would have been constructive, but, hey, that's not how you roll...).

Comment: And of course, there is the nagging little fact that the question explicitly mentioned "other Spanish airports" (so no specific reason to go to Barcelona) but you preferred to assume it had to be Barcelona apparently only for the pleasure you take in being nasty.

Comment: @Relaxed Oh, how you got me right on the spot. I thought all the time that it was not obvious how I enjoy being nasty and evil. Probably, DamianFox has some reason for wanting to fly via Barcelona, otherwise he wouldn't have asked especially about that. Perhaps there are cheap flights from his home town in Italy to Barcelona. Who knows?

Comment: Hello guys! Thanks for the many answers! Anyway, I will fly to Barcelona, since it is very cheap to fly there from Italy. So far, I haven't found yet flight at a good price to France and other spanish airport. That's why I asked how to reach the starting point of the camino from Barcelona. So, the fastest way is to go to Pamplona and then St-Jean-Pied-De-Port, right?

Answer (score 6):

As stated in comments, going to Saint Jean Pied du Port from Barcelona can take quite long. Unless necessary to go via Barcelona, try to get a flight to Bilbao or San Sebastián, so that you can decrease the travelling time. You can even check flights from Barcelona to Bilbao, which can be found for good prices.

Anyway, if you decide to go from Barcelona, you should take these steps:

- Get a bus from Barcelona to Pamplona.

  - bus company: [Alsa](http://www.alsa.es)
  - travel time: 6.30 hours
  - cost: around 30€.
  - frequency: there are buses almost every hour covering this route
  - the departure is from [Barcelona - Estació del Nord](https://www.barcelonanord.cat/en/the-station/how-to-arrive/), easy to reach with metro.
- In Pamplona, get a bus straight to Saint Jean de Pied de Port

  - bus company: again Alsa
  - travel time: 1h 45 min
  - price: around 22€
  - frequency: there are 4 buses every day covering this route from 1st March to 2 November ([source](http://www.gronze.com/introduccion-al-camino-de-santiago/c%C3%B3mo-ir-saint-jean-pied-de-port)). I just checked for tomorrow Friday 10th June and I get results at 10 h, 14.30 h and 17.30 h.